# WPF How to use Domain classes in UI

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, inotifypropertychanged

If I use Entity Framework as ORM and WPF as Presentation Technology, Do i inherit all my domain entities from INotifyPropertyChanged or Do i use a copy of each entity and make transfert each time i read from database ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question is : **MVVM** *design pattern*.

With **MVVM** i can move my domain entities to **Model** and leave them clean from UI dependencies, 
So Classes that will be written under "**ViewModel**" will inherit from **INotifyPropertyChanged** and will contain properties that will be databinded to UI (View).

Thank you..